# u-boot for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: u-boot

I'm trying to get u-boot working on Raspberry Pi 3 but so far no success.
Every time I plug in my SD card to the Pi there isn't any output to the console, only the green LED blinks several times.
 Currently I'm trying to build u-boot this way:

```
git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git

sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu

export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-

make rpi_3_defconfig

make -j8 -s
```

No errors during building, and here is what I have on my SD card:

```
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb

bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb

bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb

bootcode.bin

cmdline.txt

config.txt

fixup.dat

kernel7.img

overlays

start.elf

u-boot.bin
```

In the config.txt I wrote `kernel=u-boot.bin`

I built the kernel itself with buidroot but I think the buildroot settings don't matter since I didn't even get output from u-boot.

The kernel7.img loads just fine.

I've already tried several ways to build u-boot (using different compilers like arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi- etc., I tried to build u-boot with help of buildroot) but no luck. Every time I turn on my RPi3 the green led blinks several times and nothing shows up in the console. Please, help me with some solid way to build u-boot and make it work on RPi3.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the below entries in the `config.txt` for arm64 support :

```
arm_64bit=1
device_tree_address=0x100
device_tree_end=0x8000
```

Optionally, add '`enable_uart=1`' if you need serial console support.

If needed add `boot.scr.uimg` to the boot partition to load the kernel from u-boot (u-boot looks for this file unless you disabled auto-boot while building it) :

Prepare `boot_script.txt` :

```
fdt addr 100
fatload mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} kernel7.img
booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
```

Then run :

```
mkimage -A arm -O linux -T script -C none -n boot_script -d boot_script.txt boot.scr.uimg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing device tree overlays from `config.txt`, if you have any.

I experienced the same problem with certain overlays that seem to have overflowed or otherwise corrupted the memory allocated for the DT in U-Boot when applied by the factory bootloader. Then I could resize the DT in U-Boot and apply those overlays that otherwise failed.

```
fdt addr ${fdt_addr};
fdt resize 1024;
fatload mmc 0:1 ${fdt_addr_r} overlays/pi3-disable-bt.dtbo;
fdt apply ${fdt_addr_r};
```